# Access yaml key if absent or empty

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I want to share some ideas about how to access a key in a yaml file if the key may be empty or absent and see if there are other ways.

Consider three possible yaml files called 'dummy.yml':

```
model: phone
mode: production
```

```
model: phone
station_type: tester1
mode: production
```

```
model: phone
station_type:
mode: production
```

In Python we load the yaml into a python dictionary:

```
import yaml

with open("dummy.yml", 'r') as stream:
    try:
        config = yaml.load(stream)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
```

Now I want to access the station_type key. If the key is missing or the value is empty, we should get an empty string as the default value.

Here are some options for accessing station_type:

```
# KeyError if station_type missing:
st = config["station_type"]

# provide an empty string as the default value 
# if key is present or absent, but return None # if value is empty:
st = config.get(
"station_type", "") 

# my solution that returns a string in all three cases
st = ('' if not config.get("station_type") else config.get("station_type"))
```

Does this seem about right?

Comment: I don't really get why `config.get("station_type", "")` is not sufficient. Your third solution returns the empty string when the input is `station_type: false`, which for all I can see is not what you want.

Comment: Yes, an empty string is exactly what I want. Clearly stated above.

Comment: You stated you want the empty string when the key is empty or absent, but your code also gives the empty string when the value is `false`.

Comment: By empty, I mean the key has no value , as in the yaml example 3 above. Such a key will have a value of false in the resulting Python dictionary, but I want to return a value of empty string in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code testing your solution against a working solution:

```py
import yaml

def orig_solution(config):
  return ('' if not config.get("station_type") else config.get("station_type"))

def working_solution(config):
  return tmp if (tmp := config.get("station_type")) is not None else ""

def test(name, solution, config):
  print("\n{}:".format(name))
  val = solution(config)
  print("got value: {}".format(val))

config1 = yaml.safe_load("""
model: phone
mode: production
""")

config2 = yaml.safe_load("""
model: phone
station_type:
mode: production
""")

config3 = yaml.safe_load("""
model: phone
station_type: false
mode: production
""")

test("config1 with orig solution", orig_solution, config1)
test("config2 with orig solution", orig_solution, config2)
test("config3 with orig solution", orig_solution, config3)
test("config1 with working solution", working_solution, config1)
test("config2 with working solution", working_solution, config2)
test("config3 with working solution", working_solution, config3)
```

Output:

```
config1 with orig solution:
got value:

config2 with orig solution:
got value:

config3 with orig solution:
got value:

config1 with working solution:
got value:

config2 with working solution:
got value:

config3 with working solution:
got value: False
```

As you can see, your code returns the empty string on `config3`, which has `false` as the value. The working solution returns Python's `False`. The other inputs work with both solutions.

Now I am not completely sure which is the expected behavior in this case, but according to how you describe it, `False` should be the correct return value here and therefore your solution has a bug.

Comment: My example's config3 does not have a station type of false. It has a station type that is empty. Obviously if you type the word false, then the value is false. I'm satisfied with my solution. Thanks!

Comment: I added the example for `false` because your solution processes it differently than one might expect.

Comment: Um, what? Unclear what your contribution is hoping to achieve, but no.